# Displayig NSDate from CoreData in TableView Subtitle

Tags: uitableview, core-data, nsdate

i wanna display CoreData in my TableView with this Code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    NSManagedObject *device = [self.inventory objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell.textLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [device valueForKey:@"InventoryProductName"]]];
    [cell.detailTextLabel setText:[device valueForKey:@"expireDate"]];

    return cell;
}
```

Of course the app crashes, because of the fact that expireDate is a Date and not a string/text.
How can i display the Expire Date from my Content in the subtitle of the TableView Cell?

Comment: Use an NSDateFormatter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the date like so:

```
[cell.detailTextLabel setText:[NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:[device valueForKey:@"expireDate"] dateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle timeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle]];
```

More information [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 0):

NSDateFormatter * format=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[format setDateFormat:@"MMM dd ,yyyy HH:mm"];
NSDate * now =[device valueForKey:@"expireDate"];
NSString *dateString=[format stringFormDate;now];

Comment: and where do i insert in my saved Date?

Comment: NSDate * now =[device valueForKey:@"expireDate"];